# Creating and Parsing custom extension files c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have to create a file whose extension is different than usual file extension i.e., other than text or xml or any image files etc. say, .ikl

I am able to create such file but it is opening and contents are being exposed using notepad or notepad++.

I want that this file cannot be opened via any of such programs like notepad and even if it is it should not show actual information.

Like if we open pdf file in note pad it does not shows actual contents but lets say Garbage values..

However i want to parse this file for some values too and this parsing can be done by a program or tool created by me only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The data in a PDF isn't garbage. It's just not plain text. Anyone with the PDF specification in their hands can write code to interpret the data.

Likewise your own data. You can make it harder to read, but you can't make it impossible, not if you want your user to be able to read it again. The closest you can come is to encrypt the data using some user-provided information. E.g. the user provides the public key of some public-key encryption scheme. Then without the private key, the data is unreadable.

If you're just trying to discourage prying eyes but don't need absolute security, you can convert the data to some binary format. For example, you can kill two birds with one stone by using `GzipStream` to compress the data, making the file smaller *and* harder to read. :)

Comment: Wow, we've made pretty much the same answer at pretty much the same moment, hah. I'll delete mine. Oh, and note that for example Total Commander (quite widely used where I live) automatically detects Gzipped files and will decompress them through a simple double-click. So it might be useful to add a header etc. to break this.

Answer (score 2):

Any file can be opened in Notepad++ if you try hard enough. That is just how windows works.

The trick is to make sure that you have associated your file extension with the intended application so that the user is less inclined to mess around. This is typically acheived with a windows installation package for the 'viewer' application.

Comment: @Luaan perhaps - arguably, a file system with the feature could make it happen. I restricted it to windows because I have no idea about Linux or OSX

Comment: Well, NTFS has file encryption too, but it will always be readable to the user who created the file. A support by the file system would pretty much have to be transparent encryption, so the current user will simply see the data in clear text.

Comment: @Luaan I has only considered restricting the opening application rather than obfuscating the data. tbh though, I'm happy with how it works now!

Comment: Yeah, you can't really restrict that at all. The user can always use the Notepad++ shell extension, or just open Notepad++ first, and then drag the file inside. File extension is just a helper identification, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, it is impossible to have full control over the application actually used for opening or viewing a custom file type. However, you could use a windows shell extension to open the file with a custom viewer, as discussed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/621/Associate-File-Extension-with-Shell-OPEN-command-a). Basically, the shell extension is a registry entry directing the file to the desired application for handling it.